# ${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release directory disappears

Tags: macos, cocoapods

Pods that used to be cached in ${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release directory disappeared.
What could have caused that and why?
pod install keeps redownloading Alamofire 5.0.5 that it has downloaded like a half a dozen times already just today.

More info: I was not running any high level or low level commands that should have affected the pods cache (that I know of).

Comment: provide more info.